# Format date(mm,dd,yyy) that is being pulled from database that is populated into a textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an Asp web form (language is VB) that is used to update records in a SQL database.  The form is populated with the record with many textboxes as well as dropdownlists.  I have a textbox that is populated with a date from the record and is displayed with the date and the time. I would like change the format to only display the date as "mm-dd-yyy". In the code behind the date field is called from the database and put into the textbox via:
"MyDate.Text = dt.Rows(0)("MyDate").ToString()". 
Thanks in advance for any help that is offered.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyDate.Text = dt.Rows(0)("MyDate").ToString("MM-dd-yy");
```

See this link for a reference on what else you can do with format strings:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score -1):

In your SQL select you can format the date in this way:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(30),MyDate,110) as MyDate, ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. I don't know why I didn't think to modify the query instead of trying to format it in the code behind.

Comment: Oh well you are welcome and you can also set this question as answered to close the topic